# How to select a row in a MySql table by Username and Key and insert data in that row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a PHP Script for selecting a row by `Username` and `Key` from the Table, then inserting data into that row.

How would I go about this?

Comment: show the data for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you're trying to update a specific row. That can be done with a simple SQL statement.

```
UPDATE table_name SET user_ip = input_user_i WHERE username = your_username AND key = your_key
```

I think / hope you know how to query the database with PHP.

Comment: I Need to get this row before and i want to get it by Username and Key. Getallrows and then Filter one row Out by Username and Key

Comment: Do you really need all rows? That would make loading time much higher. With my snippet you can choose a specific row by username & key and update it directly. For sure you can do it by selecting all rows, filtering and then only update... but I'm not sure if you really need all rows. If you don't need to display them, then there's no need to select all.

Comment: Ok i have a "login script" already and i want to put that users ip in that row where the username and key are.

Comment: So everytime a user logs in, you want to save his current IP in the database? If yes, that would be quite easy and I'll edit my answer if its really what you want. But be aware that a lot of IPs today ar dynamically, means they change every 24 hours, so it isn't really worth logging IPs....

Comment: yep i want that

Comment: Okay, so you can use the query from my answer. You can update a row directly, you don't have to select all and then edit one row and write it back. Simply update the row you're looking for :)
But as I said, its not really worth logging IP's since they chance every 24 hours automatically...

Comment: In Germany the IP's only change on router Reboot, but the Programm is maked to work on Servers  ;) With an static IP

Comment: Thats not true... Also in germany you've dynamic IP's (I'm from switzerland and I'm working in a company with a lot of german customers, so I know they're changing as well as in other countrys). Since PHP is a server-side programming language its normal that your programm will work on a server. Doesn't change anything, you're website visitors will still access your websites trough a client and they'll have dynamic IP's too.